# Can't get gridsome g-image to work for grid of thumbnails

Tags: image-processing, gridsome

This is for the front page.

I've made an image collection in gridsome.server.js by scanning a folder full of images and creating nodes, each containing the name and the path of the image:

```
    let dir = fs.opendirSync(process.cwd() + '/static/images')
    let fd, fn, nameParts
    const imagesColl = actions.addCollection('images')
    while (!!(fd = dir.readSync())) {
      fn = fd.name
      nameParts = fn.split('.')
      imagesColl.addNode({
        name: nameParts[0],
        path: '/images/' + fn
      })
    }

    dir.close()
```

In the title page, I'm creating a 4x2 grid of these images.

The graphql query looks like this:

```
  images:allImages {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        path
      }
    }
  }
```

and then in my vue page component, I'm using the images like this

```
...
  <div>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-4 shadow-xl">
      <g-image width="100" v-for="(edge, ix) of $page.images.edges" :key="ix"
           :src="edge.node.path" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

So, the collection is being created just fine, I'm able to query them in the page, but It doesn't seem like the g-image processor is getting invoked at all.

I'm specifying a width of "100", which I expect to see a grid of smallish images - but it's not happening.  Basically the resulting output is just the browser sizing them down to "dumbnails" about 300px across (for this page size.)

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented [bug](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/292) in gridsome. This [comment](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/292#issuecomment-583692119) gives a workaround for a way to fix this. I've tested this solution and it has worked for me. Copying it here directly:

> Go to gridsome.config.js and add an alias for your images folder inside of the chainWebpack function (you may need to add it):

```
module.exports = {
  siteName: 'Jeremy Jackson',
  plugins: [],
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias.set('@images', '@/assets/images')
  },
  templates: {}
}
```

> Save the file and restart the server.
> Then in your code where you want to use the image you can do:

```
<g-image :src="require(`!!assets-loader!@images/${imageUrl}`)"/>
```

> And the dynamic image shows up. This works inside of v-for as well.
> For reference, here's the code I'm using inside of a v-for in my site:

```
<div id="project-images">
  <div class="section-header">Screenshots</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div 
      class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 project-image"
      v-for="(projectImage, index) in $page.project.images"
      :key="projectImage"
      @click="openLightBox(index)"
    >
      <g-image class="responsive-image" :src="require(`!!assets-loader!@images/${projectImage}`)"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Width and Height don't work with this method, [here's](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/292#issuecomment-598085445) the workaround for that:

> to specify a width/height/etc you add a query string right before the path. So the example above would become:

```
<g-image class="responsive-image" :src="require(`!!assets-loader?width=250&height=250!@images/${projectImage}`)"/>
```